# Site rebuild. Proper TFS process

Tags: tfs

We are doing a new site for one of our companies. While the new one is in development we need to be able to make edits to the old code base.

Is the proper process for this to create a branch of the project and then merge back in once it goes live?  Is there the ability to wipe the old code base when the merge takes place (if that's the correct process)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much of the old code and assets you're planning to use. If the answer is "lots", then yes, create a branch for development. If you do this, make sure to **frequently** reverse-integrate the changes from the mainline back to your development branch.

If you're pretty much tossing out the old codebase and starting from scratch, then don't bother branching, it gets you nothing.

Comment: We will be tossing the old code, but at the end of the day our convention is to match the project name to the domain. In that case would it be best to just append `NEW` to the project name and have our TFS admin move the code once we are done?  The TFS' admins group doesn't do web dev so their suggestion wasn't something I was super fond of.